# How do I call the amount of ADA sent to a validator script in an Integer

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, ada, validator

I am trying to create a validator function that only lets the user send ADA to the creator of the script if the user sends x amount of ADA how to I find out the amount of ADA the user sent and then put it in a boolean statement?

`(____ == ADA.lovelaceValueOf 30)`

Answer (score 1):

You can not disallow users to send ADA into your smartcontract script address.

You can only deny unlocking.

However you can check how much of value is being sent with outgoing transaction from txOut by checking txOutValue field.